# PHP ajax pass multiple variable onblur

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Is it possible to pass 2 variable from html input box onblur event ajax? Here is my partial code. My onblur event at 'time', i can only pass the 'time' variable to ajax.

```
<label> <span>Date</span>
<input type="date" class="input_text" name="datep" id="datep"  />
<label class="valdate" name="valdate" id="valdate"></label>
</label>

<label> <span>Time</span>
<input type="time" class="input_text" name="time" id="time"  /> 
<label class="valtime" name="valtime" id="valtime"></label>
</label>
```

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#time').blur(function(){  
       var time = $(this).val();
        var date = $('datep').val;
       $.ajax({  
            url:"checkschedule.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{schedule_time:time,schedule_date:date},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(response)  
            {  
            $('#valtime').html(response);

                var abc=document.getElementById("valtime").innerText;
                if(abc =="Duplicate time slot"){

                    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
                }else{

                    $(":submit").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            }  
       });  
    });  
 });
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It should be `$('#datep').val()` not `$('datep').val`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. @Mikey has given you the fix.